# RDS InnoDB RAM usage issue

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS RDS for a long time on a production environment.
I started monitoring it's memory usage especially InnoDB stats.

Almost whole buffer pool is full but i know that indexes created by me are not so big. Database have 32GB of RAM. MySQL version 5.7.22

After further digging i have spotted huge number of pages being used by CLUST_IND index in SYS_TABLES table and pages of type "Unknown". I am wondering if there is anything that can be done to clean it up? Any advise would be appreciated.

The query:

```
select
table_name as Table_Name, index_name as Index_Name,
count(*) as Page_Count, sum(data_size)/1024/1024 as Size_in_MB
from information_schema.innodb_buffer_page
group by table_name, index_name
order by Size_in_MB desc;
```

and result:

[image]

Comment: Question is offtopic for stackoverflow or atleast in the gray area, reask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or contact amazon support..

Answer (score 1):

`information_schema.innodb_sys_tables` is an internal list of all the tables in the system.  Do *not* mess with it.  Do *not* worry about its space usage.  "CLUST_IND" is an artificial Primary Key.

At least in the case of MySQL 5.6, it does *not* occupy disk space; it is in RAM.  And it does not actually take 4093MB.  That computation is bogus for certain system tables, such as this.

Do you have thousands of tables?  If so, consider whether *you* need all of them.  Each one is taking a little space in sys_tables.

The buffer_pool is a cache, so it is normal for it to be nearly full most of the time.  How full it is is irrelevant.